# junit data-driven tests specify when new data is given

Tags: java, selenium, junit, junit4

I am writing some webdriver tests to test the functionality of the website and now i need to make them data-driven. I am using junit to execute them. The test flow is: do login, do the test1, do logout. do login, do the test2, do logout etc.

What i need is to make both classes data driven (Login and TestClass) like so, that take first login data, do all the test with all data variations, take second login data, do all the tests with all data... etc.

So i have the main class that is calling the test classes:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({

        Test1.class,
        Test2.class,
        Test3.class
})

public class MainTestSuite {
.. skipped.
```

Test class is following:

```
public class Test1 {
    private static final Logger Log = LogManager.getLogger(Test1.class);

    @Rule
    public TestRules testRules = new TestRules();

    @Test
    public void testSomething() throws Exception { // test code
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomethingElse() throws Exception { // test code
    }
```

... skipped.

Now the login and logout are called by TestRules that is implementing the TestWatcher:

```
public class TestRules extends TestWatcher {

    @Override
    protected void starting(Description description) {
     // do login
    }

    @Override
    protected void finished(Description description) {
     // do logout
    }
```

I have been looking into the easytest module https://github.com/EaseTech/easytest-core,  but giving the parameters to login test, it loops thru all these at first and that is not what i need. Do you see any solution to my problem using the structure i already have.

Answer (score 0):

A common strategy I use is creating a Properties (or json) file that can be read by the test.

Using this method when you create a test to say, create a user, you can save the login information to the properties file, and read it with the rest of the tests.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) are the docs on properties.